# Combining then sorting 2 feeds

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I have the following script which works fine:

```
url = 'http://external_source/feed_1.xml';

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        values = data.responseData.feed.entries;
        if (values[0]) {
            for (i = 0; i <= values.length - 1; i++) {
                document.write(values[i].title);
                document.write(values[i].publishedDate);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I now have a second feed, i.e. `url = 'http://external_source/feed_2.xml';`, and I need to combine both feeds.  I understand i can repeat the above process and have feed_1 display above feed_2, but I need to combine both feeds and sort the feed entries by `publishedDate`.

How would I go about doing that?  Both feeds are structured exactly the same, they just have different values in `title` and `publishedDate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery you can use [`jQuery.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/). The example at the bottom of that page shows you how to callback after multiple async methods are finished.

Since you'll have both data returned, you can just concat the arrays and sort them thereafter:

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.json" ), $.ajax( "/page2.json" ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
  // a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively.
  // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
  var data = a1[0].responseData.feed.entries.concat(a2[0].responseData.feed.entries)
});
```